# Using @error directive to target the previous input field from multiple input fields after submit in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

The new @error directive was [introduced in Laravel 5.8.13](https://laravel-news.com/blade-error-directive). So, instead of doing this:

```html
// old
@if ($errors->has('email')) 
    <span>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span> 
@endif
```

You can now do this

```html
// new
@error('email') 
    <span>{{ $message }}</span> 
@enderror
```

However, I'm having issues trying to target only the input fields where the error was made among several similar input fields. These fields are *similar* because they have the same name. But they are also in seperate forms and have different submit buttons.

My html blade file is setup with multiple inputs generated from a `@forelse` statement. I've created a simple error check to check if a negative number is entered and to redirect back to the same page with an error message. The `@error` directive is also used to insert a custom class to target input field for styling.

```html
@forelse($accounts as $account)
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('account.update', $account->id) }}">
        @csrf
        <div>
            <input type="number" name="credit" class="@error('credit') is-invalid @enderror" required>
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="ok">
            @error('credit')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </form>
@empty
@endforelse
```

The form submits to the `update()` method in `AccountController.php`

```php
public function update(Request $request, Account $account)
{
    if($request->input('credit') < 0)
    {
        return back()->withErrors(['credit'=>'enter a positive amount']);
    }
    // ... other logic
}
```

The problem is that when a negative number is entered in one input field, the error message shows up for every input with the same name, even when they are not in the same form.

I think making the input names unique will solve this, but this will make my backend logic more complex than is required.

Is there anyway of making the error message show for just the target input after the redirect, without having to use unique names for each input field?

Comment: As you are not using the Validator, why don't you just use JS to check for a positive number instead? Then you can target each field individually. But as of the server side, you can use one error message but you have to make each field unique by setting a different name. The downside of having multiple forms on one page.

Comment: @nakov, i want the page to be fully functional, before using javascript. It's just my preferred way of coding for the web.

Comment: That's fine, then you must differentiate the input fields by giving them a different name and overriding the error message. Otherwise it will be a messy way to achieve it. I know of one, but I won't share it as it is ugly.

Comment: @nakov, do you mean the `@error` directives are always tied to a given input name?

Comment: The @error directive is just pulling from an array of elements based on a key which is the input name, so yes, it is tied to an input with a given name. So the solution below is something that I thought of as well, but I prefer using JS for such a validations. As you validation is just checking if the number is positive..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, the `@error` directive is **not** programmatically tied to any input field by an input name. It is only spatially related to an input field by proximity and can be placed any where on the page.

Also, you can conveniently use any string within the `@error` directive as long as same is passed to the `withErrors()` call in the controller.

So, solving the problem of targeting the appropriate input among multiple ones becomes as simple as using *any* unique string (*not necessarily the target input name*) as key in the `withErrors()` method call and retrieving the error message by passing the same string to the `@error` directive. In my case, I chose to use the account id as the unique string.

In `AccountController.php`:

```php
public function update(Request $request, Account $account)
{
    if($request->input('credit') < 0)
    {
        return back()->withErrors([$account->id=>'enter a positive amount']);
    }
    // ... other logic
}
```

And in the html blade template:

```html
@forelse($accounts as $account)
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('account.update', $account->id) }}">
        @csrf
        <div>
            <input type="number" name="credit" class="@error($account->id) is-invalid @enderror" required>
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="ok">
            @error($account->id)
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </form>
@empty
@endforelse
```

**NOTE**: Using a non existent key in any `@error` directive breaks the code for other @error directives and will cause no error messages to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be doing the following:

- store the value / posted form in a variable using the value of the submit button
- ditch the error directive and use the old version
- combine the old version with the variable to check wether you have the correct form or not

You'll get something like this:

```
@if ($errors->has('email') && $submitted_form_identifier === $form_identifier) 
    <span>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span> 
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `@error` directive was supposed to make this logic simpler. So, ditching it, isn't an option. I must be misunderstanding something in the usage.

Comment: @UdoE. The directive is just a piece of PHP which will be parsed when the file is generated for the cache. You're correct when you state that the directive should make things simpler, but that only applies to "standard" situations. You could easily create your own directive for this situation, which would be my advise when you want to have simple logic.