# @error directive is not displaying errors in laravel view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on custom Laravel login implementation. I have returned the error from controller as follows:

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
  // Authentication passed...
  return redirect()->intended('surveys');
}else {
  return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email', 'The Message']);
}
```

Here is my view implementation to extract this error:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
@error('email')
  <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
  </span>
@enderror
</div>
```

I want to use only this way. Not the other method to display error because of code minimization.
I'm using Laravel 7.0+

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because of Debugbar. I removed the service provider of Debugbar from config/app.php. Then @error started working again properly

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @if($errors->has('email'))  is-invalid @endif " name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
  @if($errors->has('email'))
      <div class="error"></div>
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
           <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
       </span>
  @endif
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and this works. But latest version of laravel supports above method that I'm doing.

Comment: Hope this helps : `@error('email')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</div>
@enderror`

Comment: still not working. actually error directive is not working. Also want to mention that I upgraded the version from 5.8 to 7+

Comment: hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987121/using-error-directive-to-target-the-previous-input-field-from-multiple-input-fi

Answer (score 0):

Please try it again:

```php
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
  // Authentication passed...
  return redirect()->intended('surveys');
}else {
  return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => 'The Message']);
}
```

Comment: Not working, BTW do you think you have updated something to post this answer?